# Highcharts DataLabel formatter to only show values which are not zero not working

Tags: highcharts, formatter

I currently have this one,

```
data.dataLabels = { formatter : function(){ if( this.point.y != 0 ){ return this.point.y; } } };
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(data);
```

this is suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834687/how-to-hide-zero-values-in-column-chart) and i tried it using what I put above but it did not work, it still shows values which are 0. Any help? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

my actual code looks like this,

```
            jQuery.ajax({
            url:"charts/bar_chart.php",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            data:{"tid":"<?php print $q4tid ?>"}
        }).done(
            function(data) {
                data.chart["renderTo"] = "q4chart";
                <?php if($q4title!="") { ?> 
                        data.title["text"] = "<?php print $q4title ?>";
                <?php } ?>

                //calculate approximate heigt of chart. this is needed because
                //highchart calcluate chart height based on offset height.
                var ah = data.xAxis.categories.length * (data.series.length*15);
                jQuery("#q4chart").css("height", ah+"px");

                data.dataLabels = { formatter : function(){ if( this.point.y != 0 ){ return this.point.y; } } };
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(data);

                //resize parent frame
                resizeFrame();
            }
        ).fail(
            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                jQuery("#q4chart").html("Error loading Q4 chart, please contact administrator.<br />" + errorThrown);
                //alert("Error loading Q4 Bar chart:" + errorThrown);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Works fine here as set for all series: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/mK5g8/. And works fine here for individual series: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/mK5g8/2/. Where are you actually setting it?

Comment: @wergeld see edits.that's the actual code.

Comment: What does your actual chart js look like after all of this?